# Staggered columns effect

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to achieve this effect of columns below:

[image]

And using the code below, I've been able to achieve the left side of the image. The three boxes on the left are positioned fine. **I'm not sure how to add the right column/box without effecting all of the left side**. (Note the white patch on the right is just where an image would go, don't worry about this).

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Exodus - Testing</title>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="main.css" type="text/css" media=screen>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="user_con">

            </div>
            <!-- <div class="gen_info">

            <div> -->
            <div class="rules">

            </div>
            <div class="song_con">

            </div>
            <div class="status_bar">

            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
width: 900px;
height: 700px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

/* TOP LEFT USER SECTION */
.user_con {
width: 430px; 
height: 150px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: rgba( 23,23,23,1.0);
}

/* RIGHT COLUMN (INFORMATION GENERAL) */
/* .gen_info {
width: 430px;
height: 650px;
margin: 10px;
display: inline;
float: right;
background-color: rgba( 23,23,23,1.0);
} */

/* LEFT COLUMN (RULES) */
.rules {
width: 430px; 
height: 350px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: rgba( 23,23,23,1.0);
}

/* BOTTOM LEFT COLUMN (MUSIC AND CONNECTION INFO) */
.song_con {
width: 430px;
height: 125px;
margin: 10px; 
background-color: rgba( 23,23,23,1.0);
}

/* STATUS BAR (DOWNLOAD BAR) */
.status_bar {
width: 880px;
height: 5px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: rgba( 44,44,44,1.0);
}
```

I did try adding floats and displays but none worked, at least for how I did it. I commented out the CSS and HTML for the right column to produce the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal editing, I've gotten it to look pretty close to your image.

Steps:

1. Uncommented the code for the right column (HTML & CSS)
2. Fixed the closing `.gen_info` div tag.
3. Moved `.gen_info` to the top of `.wrap`.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 900px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* TOP LEFT USER SECTION */
.user_con {
  width: 430px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 1.0);
}

/* RIGHT COLUMN (INFORMATION GENERAL) */
.gen_info {
  width: 430px;
  height: 650px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 1.0);
}

/* LEFT COLUMN (RULES) */
.rules {
  width: 430px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 1.0);
}

/* BOTTOM LEFT COLUMN (MUSIC AND CONNECTION INFO) */
.song_con {
  width: 430px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 1.0);
}

/* STATUS BAR (DOWNLOAD BAR) */
.status_bar {
  width: 880px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(44, 44, 44, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="gen_info">

  </div>
  <div class="user_con">

  </div>
  <div class="rules">

  </div>
  <div class="song_con">

  </div>
  <div class="status_bar">

  </div>
</div>
```

(Note: You may want to click "Full Page" in the snippet, otherwise the scrollbars are distracting)